# Flexbox Layout - Center and 100% Web App

Tags: html, css, web-applications, flexbox

i'm working on a web-app right now. HTMl / CSS never were a  big problem for me, except optimizing a website for Internet Explorer :) I am pretty much done with the app, there is just some "minor" stuff, which i really don't know how to solve. That's why i'm asking you for help:

I think the two layouts (screens attached) can be done by using the new flexbox, but i never worked with that before and there are so many different specs (2009, 2011, 2012…), so i don't really know where to start. The first question is just a general one: Are those two layouts possible with flexbox or HTML / CSS in general?

[image: Layout 1]
[image: Layout 2]

I tried to describe as much as possible, not really sure if its enough to understand the concept. Feel free to ask anything. Both of the layouts are more or less the same, so i think if one is possible, the other one should be doable as well somehow.

Is anybody out there, who can give me a quick and rough code sample, how to program these two layouts? It would be great for myself (to get into this flexbox thing) to describe the code just a bit (comments or something). For me it would be really helpful to at least have some sort of starting point, because at the moment i'm just stuck for days.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use Flexbox over more traditional methods?  The first one could just as easily be done using `display: table/table-cell` as it would be with Flexbox and have better browser support as a result.  The second is just a variation on that.  If you're interested in Flexbox in general, this may be of interest:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/tag/flexbox and https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: I know how to center a div with display table / table-cell, but i'm not sure how to stretch a div to the missing space available (Layout 1: purple box, Layout 2: blue box). That is why i thought about flex box first, but sure i'm interested in flexbox in general. I don't need to support IE9 and beyond, so the browser support for flexbox isn't too bad.
EDIT: Well, the support for the old spec is good, bot for the new one to be honest. So display: table / table-cell could be the better choice for now, but can you give me an CSS example for that height problem?

Comment: See:  http://timothy-long.com/responsive-sticky-footer/ or http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/.  Keep in mind that the decision to use or not use Flexbox is not entirely based on support, but how many properties+prefixes are required to do the same thing.  If you're using it, it really needs to be the *best way*.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link, i will definitely give it a try and come back, if it worked :)

Comment: I tried the table approach, just to see, how it would look like. I haven't tested the first layout yet, but i think it should be pretty easy. For the second layout the image in the blue box should have a height of 100% of the parent container. For some reason this doesn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TY2sm/

What' wrong? For the centering of the red box i used a ghost element to get rid of some HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your second example: http://jsfiddle.net/8rWwt/

I've included the non-prefix version, -ms- version, and the modern -webkit- version. The syntaxes are very similar in this example. This will be enough to support most desktop versions of Chrome still in use, Opera, and IE10 and 11. Firefox are using the latest syntax unprefixed in an upcoming version. As they auto-update, it will work across the board there shortly too.

I first make body a flex container so that the red div can be centred, and tell it to centre in both the inline and block directions:

```
body {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    -ms-flex-pack: center; 
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Now the red div is centred.

Next I add a height to the red div (otherwise there would be nothing to expand, as the hight would be the height of its children), and also make it a flex container (the green and blue divs do not become flex items unless their parent is a flex container). I then set the direction of items to column, so they stack on top of each other, rather than the default of row:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50%;

    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

It is now almost ready. The last thing that is needed is to tell the blue div to take up the remaining space:

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;

    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

If you'd like it to work in the current/old Firefox and Safari, you will need to add the syntax for old flexbox. [My article on Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/) includes tables at the bottom, mapping the syntax.

The first example is just a simplified version of the second. I removed the flexbox properties to centre the parent, and instead set the grey div to be 100% high and 100% wide. I also flipped the order of the boxes, as the green box is first and should flex:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rWwt/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed description. One more question i would like to ask you: What do you recommend to use in my case. Should i use display: table / display: table-cell or should i go for the flex box attempt, which has a worse browser support, but the HTML is simpler?

Comment: @DavidStorey I love your article on Smashing Magazine help me a lot to understand how flexbox works.

Comment: @DavidStorey I just tried your your code and modified it a bit. It should work now with Safari / Firefox and i combined Layout 1 and Layout 2 into one Layout. In the end it should be a slider, which contains different slides. Each of these slides (".slider__slider") should be 100% / 100% (relative to the body). I uploaded my code, so you can have a look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/tgvVN/

Comment: It works like it should on Safari (Version 6), but it doesn't on Chrome (Latest). It doesn't work on Firefox either, but i think its because Firefox doesn't support % values as width. I may need to use JS to fix that. But what is wrong with Chrome? Safari looks all right.

Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! and here is a [big tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/)

**Your first wish:**

**[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/onuneg/2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
    <div class="green">
        big<br>
        test<br>
        content<br>
        very<br>
        big<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.parent{
  display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
  display: -moz-box;      /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */ 
  display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21+ */
  display: flex;          /* NEW: Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */

  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  -moz-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  -o-flex-flow: column; 
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.purple{
  display: -webkit-box; display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -moz-box-flex: auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto;
  background: purple;
}
.green {
  display: -webkit-box; display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
  background: green; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats long, i will read it as soon as i tried the solution by cimmanon

Comment: Flexbox is really big right now... many prefix... you should take care about it

Comment: Yeah you are right with the prefixes. Just seen your live example, thank you very much for that. Works for me on Chrome, but doesn't seem to work for Safari 6 so far. But i think it's because the green box is missing the -webkit attributes. I will take a look at it and see, if i should go for flexbox or stick with table / table-cell (as cimmanon mentioned above). Not really sure right know.